# How to enable second screen (HDMI)

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I am new to Linux and this forum.
I hope you can help me to solve another Linux mystery...

I have installed ubuntu 11.10, selected Additional Drivers/activated second driver (to utilisy Unity). 
My GPU is nvidia GT330M (laptop).

In Windows I often connect PC via HDMI and main display form LCD switches to display on TV (SONY Z5500). No problems at all.

In Linux - well... its a nother hardware nightmare. Heres what I did:

1) connected HDMI cable TV<>PC
2) turned on TV
3) run as sudo nvidia-settings
4) detect displays - TV found, unmarked  and put in TVs settings X Separate Screen
5) apply and save to xconf file
6) reboot PC

Rebooted.

Unfortunately NOTHING has changed - TV does not detect any HDMI devices (sources), Nvidia settings show tv is there, but when i run display manager via system settings - only LCD display is being shown.

How to change the display from LCD to TV?

Here is my output of xconf file

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings: version 280.13 (buildd@allspice) Thu Aug 11 20:54:45 UTC 2011

Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier "Layout0"
Screen 0 "Screen0" 0 0
Screen 1 "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
InputDevice "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
InputDevice "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
Option "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
# generated from default
Identifier "Mouse0"
Driver "mouse"
Option "Protocol" "auto"
Option "Device" "/dev/psaux"
Option "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
# generated from default
Identifier "Keyboard0"
Driver "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
# HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
Identifier "Monitor1"
VendorName "Unknown"
ModelName "SONY AVAMP"
HorizSync 14.0 - 70.0
VertRefresh 48.0 - 62.0
Option "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
# HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
Identifier "Monitor0"
VendorName "Unknown"
ModelName "Seiko/Epson"
HorizSync 30.0 - 75.0
VertRefresh 60.0
Option "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "Device1"
Driver "nvidia"
VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName "GeForce GT 330M"
BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
Screen 1
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "Device0"
Driver "nvidia"
VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName "GeForce GT 330M"
BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
Screen 0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen1"
Device "Device1"
Monitor "Monitor1"
DefaultDepth 24
Option "TwinView" "0"
Option "metamodes" "DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
SubSection "Display"
Depth 24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen0"
Device "Device0"
Monitor "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth 24
Option "TwinView" "0"
Option "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
SubSection "Display"
Depth 24
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

---

- UPDATE : I just managed to do something - I have resetted all settings, put Seiko and Sony to Separate X window, saved, reboot, and then I have checked sources in tv again.

Of course no change so I enforced to show HDMI 1 (cable is connected in ) and switched to it.

Now TV screen went white, when I clicked on it (there was mouse pointer which looks like black X) it turned black. No options, no tasbar, no nothing except black background and X pointer)

Funny thing is when I hit ctrl+alt+1 (change to 1st terminal) output went to TV screen! I could see  login?

What the heck?
Any advices?

Comment: I suggest to enable "TwinView" in nvidia-settings. seperate x screen means really seperate - you cannot move applications between them etc. The effect with the terminal is quite normal as the terminal uses another generic graphics driver and always prints to any screen found. Twinview will give you the capabilities to move applications between the monitors as both monitors are handled as one big screen.

Comment: Well, I do not want to clone the image. I would like the content of laptop display 'moved' to TV display, so laptop will be blank. Thats why separate screen would work out for me best - I would set up env in TV separately to PC - but got only black screen...

Comment: so you want the internal screen to be disabled and the external one being the only monitor available?

Comment: thats correct. but when hdmi cable unplugged display should move back to laptop. setting up two differents displays (separate X) would also work (one display for PC, separate for TV). problem is - cant see anything on TV screen. btw later on I will  set TV as my primary display and switch off Laptop. We will see if it works with one re-directed display.

Comment: Just managed it to work - got separate X Window for both displays, then turned off PC display and set primary for TV - it worked after restart!

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out "got separate X Window for both displays, then turned off PC display and set primary for TV - it worked after restart!"